# Seperate values from string in between characters in php

Tags: php, string

I have a string ("`$big_string`") in php with is combination of small section of strings("`$string`") like this one `"-val1(sec1)-"`, for eg :

```
$string1="-val1(sec1)-";
$string2="-val2(sec2)-";
$string3="-val3(sec3)-";
$big_string=$string1.$string2.$string3;
```

How can I separate values from $big_string to an array-like

the `val1..` and so on values are between `'-'` & `'('`
and the `sec1...` and so on values are beteen `'('` & `')-'`

```
$array[0][0]="val1";
$array[0][1]="sec1";
$array[1][0]="val2";
$array[1][1]="sec2";
$array[2][0]="val3";
$array[2][1]="sec3";
```

**Edit:** I received the $big_string as input, above code is for ref that how $big_string is constructed.

Comment: You generate those strings (`$string1`, `$string2` and `$string3`) or you just get it like this and you cant change it?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal Sir the string i received is $big_string, I added the above example to demonstrate how $big_string is constructed.

Comment: that wasnt my question. My question was if you have any influence to change the string you recieve, for example can you change it to `".val1(sec1)."`, is that a possiblity, yes or no?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal Yes I can ask the user (string received from a function by some other code) to give string in format `.var1(sec1).` instead of `-var1(sec1)-`

Comment: A way more secure way would be to use [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), easily encoded and securely decoded. [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal sir, I understand your concern but am restricted to PHP only.

Comment: json_encode and json_decode are php functions.

Comment: Yes, have a look at JSON encode and decode, that's much better than any of the answers below.

Comment: Yes, I got it used to create to JSON format from json_encode() in PHP, but sir, sorry for the inconvenience i forgot to type "String", I wanted to say restricted to PHP string only.

Comment: I feel like ive said more than enough, but just so i can sleep in peace tonight: json generates a string, so if you have any influence, tell the person who sends your `$big_string` should do so in the json format (which is nothing but a string). You can then decode the string you want to a perfect array structure without any problems. If you are stuck with this string format then see the answers below.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal , thanks for your effort sir, i will also learn json_encode() & json_decode(), but sir I can not change $big_string in this case, I just received it and have to do work on it exactly what I have received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep my code simple, using basic PHP functions. Something like this:

```
$big_string = '-val1(sec1)--val2(sec2)--val3(sec3)-';

$val_sec_array = explode('--', trim($big_string, '-'));
foreach ($val_sec_array as $val_sec) {
    $array[] = [strstr($val_sec, '(', TRUE),
                trim(strstr($val_sec, '('), '()')];
}

print_r($array);
```

The first line uses `trim()` to trim off the excess `'-'` at the begin and end of the `$big_string` and then explodes the remaining string into an array on each `'--'` it encounters.

The `foreach` loop then takes that array and uses `strstr` to first get the section before the `'('` from the string and then the section after the `'('`. The `'('` and `')'` are then trimmed off the latter section. The two values then form an array `[ ... , ... ]` and are stored in the main array.

This is funny, saying it like this makes it sound more complex than it really is. Just look in the manual how this works:

- [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
- [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [strstr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)
- [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thank you sir it worked like charm, can u please add the comments so that I can learn how this is functioning.

Comment: I will try, but most of it you can find in [the manual](https://php.net).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$string1 = "-val1(sec1)-";
$string2 = "-val2(sec2)-";
$string3 = "-val3(sec3)-";
$big_string = $string1 . $string2 . $string3;

if (preg_match_all('/-([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)-/', $big_string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    $result = array_map(static fn($match) => array_slice($match, 1), $matches);
    print_r($result);
}
```

If you're using PHP < 7.4, the line with `$result` can be changed into this:

```
$result = array_map(static function ($match) {
    return array_slice($match, 1);
}, $matches);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/2Etfk)

Comment: Side notes: assuming `$string3 = "-val3()-";` would be the case then it would skip the pair `'val3' => ''`. If this is intended or unintended is not clear by the question itself. Also this shows uninteded behavior if for example `$string2 = "-val2()-";` (with `$string3 = "-val3(sec3)-";`) would be the case. Still noteworthy in my opinion.

Comment: Right, depends if what's between parentheses can be empty or not. In which case changing `+`'s to `*`'s may be needed.